# Specific url redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have this domain "www.mydomain.com/great/redirect"

I want to redirect it to "www.redirect.com/great/redirect"

using .htaccess so how can I do that?

Right now I am doing that using html

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://redirect.com/great/redirect" />
```

in location of "www.mydomain.com/great/redirect" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside site root .htaccess of `www.mydomain.com` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^great/redirect/?$ http://redirect.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Are there more rules in site root .htaccess or just this one? Is .htaccess enabled?

Comment: can you just show me that if I enter this link "http://example.com/great/redirect"

It must take me to "http://example.org/great/redirect" using .htaccess

Above thing is not working

PS - Domain are .com and org as comment doesn't allow taking other domains

Comment: yes enabled and I tried to check that but didn/t work

Comment: I asked 2 questions in my comment

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

this are rules placed before

Comment: My suggested rule should be placed as first rule just below `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112330/discussion-between-siren-brown-and-anubhava).