# htaccess redirect based on 404 and text in url

Tags: .htaccess

I need to know how to redirect a user when a 404 is found and the url contains specific text.

Let's say I have this url:

www.mysite.com/northeast-articles/cooking-with-butter.html

And that URL is now expired as the cooking-with-butter.html article is unpublished.

I'd like to know how to do this in my htaccess file:

IF the referring text generates a 404

AND the referring text contains "northeast-articles"

THEN route the user to  www.mysite.com/northeast-main-page

With this approach when the article is unpublished and thus expired it won't generate a 404 but instead will take the user to the "main" northeast page.  And we won't have to manually code redirects for every article that expires.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specific url redirect using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308484/specific-url-redirect-using-htaccess)

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a similar questions with an accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308484/specific-url-redirect-using-htaccess). Please check it.

Comment: Thank you Syfer, but that's not exactly what I need.  I need a 404 to be triggered first, then if that 404 was triggered by a URL containing "northeast-articles" I want to redirect the user.  The post you mentioned appears to just always do a redirect.  The redirect isn't conditional.